# Add part to a URL via htaccess

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have asked another question on here with the premise of limiting download speeds via PHP and I have since come to conclusion that using mod_limitrate was the best solution. so using the following code I have successfully managed to limit the download speed.

```
<Location "/limit5">
    SetOutputFilter RATE_LIMIT
    SetEnv rate-limit  5120
    SetEnv rate-initial-burst 5120
</Location>

<Location "/unlimited">
    SetOutputFilter RATE_LIMIT
    SetEnv rate-limit  204800
    SetEnv rate-initial-burst 204800
</Location>
```

However my file structure was not built with this in mind so everything is on the / directory, the following is my file structure

```
/downloads
-> /downloads/1.zip
-> /downloads/2.zip
...
...
```

Which makes my download links `https://example.com/downloads/1.zip` so is it possible to add a part to the URL such as `https://example.com/limit5/downloads/1.zip` however would still direct to `https://example.com/downloads/1.zip` ?

I am presuming `htaccess` is the answer, but I'm not sure how to go about this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this rule in your Apache `VirtualHost` config or in site root .htaccess:

```bash
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^/?\w+(/downloads/.+)$ $1 [L,NC]
```

If you want to allow only 2 parts before `downloads/` then use:

```bash
RewriteRule ^/?(?:limit5|unnlimited)(/downloads/.+)$ $1 [L,NC]
```

Comment: Bottom solution for just two parts worked flawlessly thanks, my legacy URLs still work too!